# Transpose table in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

I was looking for button where I can transpose the table on one click in powerpoint, I have tried few script's but it's not working for me, sharing below for you to understand what I am trying, and Looking for your help to correct me where I am doing wrong.

```
Sub TransposeTable()
    Dim slide As Slide
    Dim table As Table
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim numCols As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim tempArray() As Variant
    Dim newTable As Table
    
    ' Check if the first slide is selected and has a table
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type <> ppSelectionSlides Then
        MsgBox "Please select a slide.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set slide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)
    
    ' Check if the first shape on the slide is a table
    If slide.Shapes.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The selected slide does not have any shapes.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each shape In slide.Shapes
        If shape.Type = msoTable Then
            Set table = shape.Table
            numRows = table.Rows.Count
            numCols = table.Columns.Count
            
            ' Create a temporary array to store the transposed table data
            ReDim tempArray(1 To numCols, 1 To numRows)
            
            ' Transpose the table data into the temporary array
            For i = 1 To numRows
                For j = 1 To numCols
                    tempArray(j, i) = table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                Next j
            Next i
            
            ' Delete the existing table
            table.Delete
            
            ' Create a new transposed table at the same position
            Set newTable = slide.Shapes.AddTable(NumRows:=numCols, NumColumns:=numRows, Left:=shape.Left, Top:=shape.Top, Width:=shape.Height, Height:=shape.Width).Table
            
            ' Populate the new table with the transposed data
            For i = 1 To numCols
                For j = 1 To numRows
                    newTable.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tempArray(i, j)
                Next j
            Next i
            
            Exit Sub ' Transpose only the first table found
        End If
    Next shape
    
    ' No table found
    MsgBox "The selected slide does not contain a table.", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the errors you are getting (if any), or what the incorrect output looks like now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code: 1. A table cannot be deleted in the way you try, its parent/the shape should be deleted. 2. After deleting the shape, the reference to it is lost. So you must preliminarily memorize the involved shape necessary properties (Left, Top, Height and Width) and use them after deletion:

```
Sub TransposeTable()
    Dim slide As slide, table As table, numRows As Long, numCols As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, tempArray() As Variant
    Dim newTable As table, Sh As Shape, shLeft As Double, shTop As Double, shHeight As Double, shWidth As Double
    
    ' Check if the first slide is selected and has a table
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type <> ppSelectionSlides Then
        MsgBox "Please select a slide.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set slide = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)
    
    ' Check if the first Sh on the slide is a table
    If slide.Shapes.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The selected slide does not have any Shs.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each Sh In slide.Shapes
        If Sh.Type = msoTable Then
            Set table = Sh.table
            numRows = table.Rows.Count
            numCols = table.Columns.Count
            
            ' Create a temporary array to store the transposed table data
            ReDim tempArray(1 To numCols, 1 To numRows)
            
            ' Transpose the table data into the temporary array
            For i = 1 To numRows
                For j = 1 To numCols
                    tempArray(j, i) = table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                Next j
            Next i
            
            shLeft = Sh.Left: shTop = Sh.Top
            shHeight = Sh.Height: shWidth = Sh.Width
            
            ' Delete the existing table
            table.Parent.Delete
            
            ' Create a new transposed table at the same position
            Set newTable = Slide.Shapes.AddTable(numRows:=numCols, NumColumns:=numRows, _
                Left:=shLeft, Top:=shTop, Width:=shWidth / numCols * numRows, _
                Height:=shHeight / numRows * numCols).table
            
            ' Populate the new table with the transposed data
            For i = 1 To numCols
                For j = 1 To numRows
                    newTable.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tempArray(i, j)
                Next j
            Next i
            
            Exit Sub ' Transpose only the first table found
        End If
    Next Sh
    
    ' No table found
    MsgBox "The selected slide does not contain a table.", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Now, the code should work but I do not know how changing the respective dimensions will affect the slide space, against the other existing shapes, if any...

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: You could also treat the tables themselves as arrays; for a table that's x rows by y columns, create a new one that's y rows by x columns, then iterate through the cells more or less as you've done with the arrays. Finally, delete the original table.  Sizing tables, though, doesn't work the way sizing other shapes does; a table's row height will never shrink below the minimum required to hold any text in any cell in that row.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg Yes, there are also more staff to be optimized but I've just tried to emphasize what's wrong in the original code and how to be adapted in order to work. He maybe has short headers (in terms of used digits), I took the theme as it was describe by OP...

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru it works perfectly as I wanted, only the dimension of Tables are changing... If that also works fine so that will be great

Comment: @Zahid Khan What do you mean by "only the dimension of Tables are changing"? Do you mean that the previous table Height value is not the previous Width one, after running the code?

Comment: @FaneDuru yeah I was talking about height and width value of the table is drastically changed, sharing attached reference for you before and after running the script

https://prnt.sc/NCe6KbJt7M7v

Comment: @Zahid Khan Not exactly "drastically" in terms of what I tried doing... :) I mean, the table height becomes the former table width and the same for width... I did not pay too much attention to this aspect. I think it can be handled (better) by calculation of dimensions in a different way. It should look perfect if all rows/columns have the same size. I will adapt the code in 1 to 2 minutes...

Comment: @Zahid Khan Please, test the adapted code and send some feedback. As I said, it will return nicely (for all the table) only if the rows and columns of the table to be transposed are equal in terms of size. I mean equal rows height and equal columns width... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru Hey thanks buddy it's now working perfect, what exactly I was looking for, I will work from my side to transpose the formatting also of the Table... Once again Thanks alot